# Get the json which is in NSData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, nsdata

I'm new in Objective-c. I want to make an HTTPRequest to an API. 
This works, I get my response in an NSData object. This response
is a json response. How can I parse my response to get a dictionary
with key: value format?

I used this code to get the data:

```
  data = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: req
                             returningResponse: nil
                                         error: nil];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (iOS5+) to convert JSON strings to Cocoa objects (`NSDictionary` in your case) and vice-versa.

PS : If you need to also support iOS versions before 5.0, namely where the `NSJSONSerialization` is not available, there are third-party libraries out there, like [`JSONKit`](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) for example. You may then either always use `JSONKit` both on iOS4 and iOS5, or your may test at runtime for `NSJSONSerialization` availability and use it if available (but fallback to `JSONKit` if not).

*(For more details on cross-SDK development, like making and app compatible with iOS4 but being able to use iOS5 classes when available, see the [SDK Compatibility Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Introduction/Introduction.html))*

---

By the way, you should (must) avoid using synchronous URL requests. This will block your thread until it receives the response from the network. If you execute it on the main thread, your whole UI will be frozen until you receive the response, which can take several seconds in a mobile environment (where you don't always have the best network coverage).

Prefer:

- using the API of NSURLConnection that uses a delegate (See [the URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html) for details),
- or using the newly introduced `sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` method (iOS5+) that will execute the request in a background NSOperation,
- or use some third-party framework that will make your work with requests easier (I recommend [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) for that, which is also great for communicating with WebServices and automatically convert the response to a JSON object, uses blocks to handle the response asynchronously and make your code easier to write and understand, and much more)

Comment: Ok Grea, this is working. The fact is, I have json in json, I mean I have something like that: 
    [{key1:value1, key2:
                         {key3: value3,
                          key4: value4}, key5:value5}]

How can I get the key3

Comment: That's not a problem. You will obtain a Cocoa object with the exact same structure as your JSON object. In your example, you will get an `NSArray` (the "[ ... ]" in the JSON construct) containing a single `NSDictionary` with 3 keys : `key1`, `key2` and `key5`. `key1` will contain the `value1` value, `key5` will contain `value5`, and `key2` will contain another (inner) `NSDictionary` with 2 keys `key3` and `key4` that have values `value3` and `value4`. _(You can `NSLog` the object returned by your NSJSONSerialization to understand it structure if it helps)_